# Program crashes while executed in release visual c++

Tags: visual-c++-2008

I have just begun to use Visual C++ 2008 to create an app for my PC. 
Program work both in debug and release mode when its run from visual c++.

When I run release when is visual c++ closed and click on buttons unhandled exception occurred.

So what does that actually mean? How to solve the problem ?

Thanks

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
 just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a character.
   at System.Convert.ToChar(Int32 value)
   at gorskikotar.Form1.chekSum(String DtCS) in c:\users\freza\desktop\ozalj jednajedinica v100\gorskikotar\form1.h:line 1151
   at gorskikotar.Form1.slanjeKomande(String tip, String group, String unit, String komanda) in c:\users\freza\desktop\ozalj jedna jedinica v100\gorskikotar\form1.h:line 1127
   at gorskikotar.Form1.testAlarmi(String group, String unit) in c:\users\freza\desktop\ozalj jedna jedinica v100\gorskikotar\form1.h:line 1024
  at gorskikotar.Form1.uredajiZaTest() in c:\users\freza\desktop\ozalj jedna jedinica v100\gorskikotar\form1.h:line 1011
   at gorskikotar.Form1.button8_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\freza\desktop\ozalj jedna jedinica v100\gorskikotar\form1.h:line 529
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... You are using a character literal that somehow is illegal, like a negative number or a very large number to the `ToChar` call. Check your source code at the lines reported to see what it might be. Even while it might not crash when you debug, _use the debugger_! Set a breakpoint at e.g. line 1151 of the file form1.h, which is where you call `ToChar`, to see if you pass valid integers to the function.

Comment: I dont see error in my code :
http://pastebin.com/140ECRR0

Comment: This errors happens only when I run release inside of Visual c++

Comment: Just for fun, print the values of `a` and `b`, together with the values for `Char::MinValue` and `Char::MaxValue`. Then you will surely see when you will get the error. I also recommend you read the "Exception" section of the [`ToChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx.aspx) documentation page.

Comment: `Console::WriteLine(L"a = {0}, b = {1}, max = {2}, min = {3}", a, b, Char::MaxValue, Char::MinValue);`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg

Should I use some another conversion when i trying to convert char to string ? (I can't find the error)

Comment: I try using the debugger and in release(when is run from visual c++) arguments that I pass to function are valid integers

Comment: Yes, they may be valid _integers_, but are the values valid as _characters_?

Comment: they are between 0 and 128...
For exemple `Console::WriteLine(L"a = {0}, b = {1}, max = {2}, min = {3}", a, b, Char::MaxValue, Char::MinValue);`
print
a=66, b=123, max=, min=

Comment: @JoachimPileborg
 I find some error ... When I  run release from directory (when is visual c++ closed ) then print :
a=152748, b=224, max=, min=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem: In the code you linked to (it should really be in the question) you declare the variable `sum`, but you do not *initialize* it. Visual Studio is helpful and clears it for you, but when running outside of VS, then this variable can be anything.

Change declaration line to:

```
long  sum = 0, i, a, b;
```

Comment: That reslove my problem.
Thanks :)